# Expo How to write a eas.json file for both ios and android?

Tags: react-native, expo

Im not sure what to add to the eas.json file when Im building for both ios and android and think the build error I got might came from me adding the wrong things to the file. How do I do it correctly?

for ios its suppose to be this:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.7.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "enterpriseProvisioning": "universal"
      }
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

for android this:

```
{
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Im not sure how to add a file for both ios and android so I did the following:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.7.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "enterpriseProvisioning": "universal"
      },
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using eas build command and use eas build --profile development --platform all

```
    "cli": {
        "version": ">= 5.6.0"
    },
    "build": {
        "development": {
            "distribution": "internal",
            "developmentClient":true,
            "android": {
                "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
            },
            "ios": {
                "buildConfiguration": "Debug"
            }
        },
        "preview": {
            
        },
        "production": {}
    }
}
```

this should work if you just copy paste same stuff in to preview or just leave them empty(unless you need some specific stuff) eas handles the process and gives you apks/iap's without issue that you can use. Currently if i use eas build --profile preview --platform ios i can send my iap to testflight without issue